# How to prevent ssh login in Ubuntu 12.04 for users without home directory?

Tags: ssh, login

I have LDAP auth configuration and I want to prevent user to have access to a computer
without home directory on it.
**Console login** and **kdm login** work fine - user access is denied, but `sshd`
permits to login with home directory `/`.

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: This same question has been asked here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68745/restrict-ssh-login-from-ldap-to-users-who-have-a-home-directory

Comment: Thank you. It is very usefull article. It seems that a module "pam_homecheck" helps in this problem, but it is absent in Ubuntu.

Comment: A direct way to do this - add into /etc/bash.bashrc:

[[ ! -x $HOME ]] && { echo "Error: No home directory. Bye."; exit 1; }

Answer (score 0):

You are able to specify which users that have access the server by configuring the

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config:
     AllowUsers admin bob
```

You can list all users by hand or extract them by creating a start up script.